# Stiching screenshots with overlap without projection mapping

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-stitching

I'm trying to stitch together screenshots. These screenshots have overlap to ensure I can correctly locate the screenshots in relation to each other.

I've tried stitching them together with OpenCV via cv2::Stitcher. This seems to be extensively documented for panoramic photos, but not as well on stack overflow for scans. I tried the below code, but it only seems to work for some subset of the photos, with some consecutive pairs of the photos returning an error. My code is below.

```py
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__) # 4.6.0

#mode=0 photos, mode=1 scans
stitcher = cv2.Stitcher.create(mode=1)

img = []
for i in range(1,30):
    img.append(cv2.imread(f"pics/{i}.png"))

result = stitcher.stitch(img)
cv2.imwrite("stitched.png", result[1])
```

I seem to get an error where sometimes some images seem to be just dropped and other times images seem to be attached diagonally and resized.

Comment: please also add the error message

Comment: Please show your images. You can post to some free hosting service and put the URL in your post or a comment.